# How to dynamically change the content of a textBlock inside another method?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-forms-designer

I have a search method (an extended SQL query within) which is triggered by a "search" button. I wish to show "Running..." in a TextBlock while the code is running and to show "Done" when it ends. Ideally the "Done" message also replaced by an "Idle" message after a few seconds.

Relevant part of my XAML code is this:

```
<Button x:Name="MainButton" Click="searchButton_Click" Content="search" ... />
<TextBlock Name="status" Text="Idle" .../>
```

and the relevant part of my C# code is as follows:

```
namespace WpfApp5
{

   public partial class MainWindow : Window 
   {


        public MainWindow()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void searchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        this.status.Text="running...";
  
        // make connection

        string mySQLquery= "Do a lot of things here...";

  

        // show the result in a datagrid
        SqlCommand my_cmd = new SqlCommand(mySQLquery, conn);

        DataTable mydt = new DataTable();

        using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(my_cmd))
        {
           a.Fill(mydt);
        }

        this.status.Text="done";

        }
    }
}
```

What this code does is that it shows "idle" in TextBlock when the app opens and then doesn't change it, till the search process is done; and then shows "done". So the "running" state doesn't appear.
I would like to have a solution with minimal changes in the logic of my code. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe it's just too fast for you to see "running..."? Did you try adding a breakpoint after this line to see if it gets written correctly?

Comment: @Rafalon No, it's not that fast. It takes several seconds. You mean the logic of this code is right? I think there's a problem here.

Comment: I mean it *seems* right to me, but maybe there's some buffer involved or anything… **Edit:** ok I didn't know that WPF wouldn't update UI until method is exited (which I learnt thanks to Quercus below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your query asynchronously. WPF won't update UI until method is exited.
You can mark you handler as async and use `Task.Run` to make sql query:

```cs
private async void searchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.status.Text="running...";

    // make connection

    string mySQLquery= "Do a lot of things here...";



    // show the result in a datagrid
    SqlCommand my_cmd = new SqlCommand(mySQLquery, conn);

    DataTable mydt = new DataTable();

    await Task.Run(() => {
       using (SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(my_cmd))
       {
          a.Fill(mydt);
       }
    });

    this.status.Text="done";

    await Task.Delay(2000);
 
    this.status.Text = "idle";

}
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you! Now it shows "running..." when it runs and then "done" when it finishes. Is there a simple way to replace the "done" with "idle" after some seconds?

Comment: Sure, add `await Task.Delay(2000); this.status.Text="idle";` to the end of method, for 2 second delay. However, if you will press button before done will change to idle you'll see at first 'running' and then suddenly 'idle' - as long as two button handlers will work together

Comment: Can you please add this to your answer? I don't know where I should add this part. I thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're running the `searchButton_click` function on the UI thread, the UI won't update until the function is done.

```
private void searchButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // starts the lambda outside the UI thread
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // dispatcher will execute the lambda inside the UI thread
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            Status.Text = "running...";
        });
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            Status.Text = "done";
        });
        SetDefaultPromise();
    });
}

private void SetDefaultPromise()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            Status.Text = "idle";
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't try it because the previous reply solved the problem of "running...". But is there any way to change the status to "idle" after some seconds of showing the "done" ?

Comment: @Iraj I edited to take into account your need.

Comment: Thank you very much